# view class option not showing in android studio

Tags: android-studio, class, import, view

I have tried **Alt + Enter**, but can't see the import option in the menu. There are only create options. *How to import **view class** in android studio.*

Answer (score 0):

Your build is probably broken. Check the Build tab and the gradle console for any issues and also your build.gradle files for any typos or problems with the code.